# Short story - aliens seek the wisdom of "Jimmy Dodd" (host of Mickey Mouse Show)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in Asimov's from the 80s or 90s. There's a mission sent to an alien world that contacted Earth seeking guidance from Earth's greatest philosopher - Jimmy Dodd (host of the Mickey Mouse club).  The human mission includes a woman old enough to have watched the show (and I think to have met Dodd and run a fan club) - she loved Dodd's sermonettes because her family life was awful.   She becomes ends up staying with the aliens to guide them, since they are going through a cultural crisis (they know about Dodd through picking up Earth TV - but they're not up to "Mr. Rogers").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "[Not Without Honor](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42019)" by Judith Moffett.

It first appeared in the May 1989 issue of *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine*.

A snippet from a [goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/3656626037?book_show_action=true) of this issue:

> Aliens have come to Earth on the basis of watching The Mickey Mouse
> Club and are mortified to find that Jimmie Dodd has died in Judith
> Moffett’s “Not Without Honor.”

The story can be read [here](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v13n05_1989-05/page/n69/mode/2up).

Comment: Thank you!  "M-o-u-s-e!"